# In the console window I keep getting this error undefined (reading 'takeRecords')

Tags: typescript

Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'takeRecords')
at Function.e.closeListeners (chrome-extension://clmkdohmabikagpnhjmgacbclihgmdje/content-script.js:1:5858)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in one of the chrome extensions. I searched for "Function.e.closeListeners" and the first on the list is Eno. Look for Eno in my extensions. Eno from CapitalOne is on, I turned it off and the error went away. Just want to share in case somebody else gets the same error.